# Statements completely ignored (as if: omitted by compiler?)

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Well I've hit the brick once again.. Again something I don't see the reason it is wrong and have no idea how to make it work:

I have an instance of class *Human*. The class *Human* is derived from *Object*.. The *Object* class has a vitrual function called "PerformStep". The *Human* Class overloads this function.
*Human* class also has the function "WalkAction". Now I want to call this "walkaction" during the PerformStep - By member function pointer.
I like to do this by pointer as:
Humans are dumb: they know **how** to walk, but not **when**. So a god-instance would be asked during the step: "what shall I do now" - And then that god instance returns the pointer to the correct member function.

```
virtual void PerformStep() 
{
    postion.x += 0; //redundant line to check for the debugger
    CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this,&Human::WalkAction);
    Object::PerformStep();
}
```

Human::WalkAction:

```
void WalkAction(){
    position.x += 1;
}
```

CALL_MEMBER_FN (macro):
 `CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))`

The problem is that when I run the program in debug mode, it **completely** ignores the line with the function pointer. - If I run it statement-by-statement it "jumps" over the line, if I put a breakpoint in walk action it never reaches the breakpoint.. If I put a breakpoint on the specific line, the breakpoints gets shoved to the next line.

What is happening here?

Comment: The macro just makes the code harder to read, ditch it. The C++ FAQ is wrong in this regard. It's trivial to just learn the proper syntax, and doesn't confuse those that understand it already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That macro does nothing in this context, it just expands to a pointer to function.  To actually call the function, you need an extra pair of parentheses.

```
myObj->myfunc;   // does nothing
myObj->myFunc(); // calls the function
```

I expect the compiler has optimized this out, so there's no code to be executed or to break on.  You could see this clearly by:

- not using the macro in the first place (preferred)
- using your compiler's option to output source code interleaved with corresponding assembler.

Comment: The macro seems to be endorsed by the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.6.

Comment: THIS is NOT what I mean.. I DONT want to explicitelly call the function: I want to call it by FUNCTION POINTER..

Comment: Just like in the "for_each" command, you don't provide function pointers with parenthesis!

Comment: @Oli, yes but note the usage immediately below its definition.  It actually calls the func, with two params.

Comment: @Oli: But then it must be used as `CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this,&Human::WalkAction) ();`. I.e. you have to supply arguments. Which makes sense.

Comment: @paul23 - and if you were to use it with `for_each`, it would work.  It just won't work as you described in your question.  Compare your usage to the example in Oli's link for the source of this macro - `int ans = CALL_MEMBER_FN(fred,p)('x', 3.14);`

Comment: ow sorry, I just noticed that indeed I was wrong.. - I needed those parentheses.. (though the way I like the macro to work is by doing this:

Comment: np @paul32, I find this stuff opaque every time as well.  Though I still prefer binders to macros.